# Get Full URL with PHP & Include Subdomain

Tags: php

I have been using the following to discover the full url, but it does not detect the subdomain I am calling from.

```
$current_url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."";
echo $current_url;EXIT;
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` should include the subdomain. Can you link us to an example page?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and works fine for me. Used this code:

```
<?
$current_url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."";
echo $current_url;EXIT;
?>
```